# add data from 1 array to the other

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

after looking through loads of questions on here i still carnt find an answer that suits my situation.

im trying to join 2 fields from array #2 into array #1

Array #1

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [position] => top_banner_1
            [name] => Top Banner 1
            [order] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [position] => left_banner_1
            [name] => Left Banner 1
            [order] => 2
        )
)
```

Array #2

```
Array
(
    [status] => 0
    [countries] => 
    [module_status] => 1
    [top_banner_1_status] => 1
    [top_banner_1_display] => 0
    [left_banner_1_status] => 1
    [left_banner_1_display] => 0
    [left_banner_2_status] => 1
    [left_banner_2_display] => 0
    [left_banner_3_status] => 1
    [left_banner_3_display] => 0
    [left_banner_4_status] => 
    [left_banner_4_display] => 0
    [left_banner_5_status] => 
    [left_banner_5_display] => 0
    [center_banner_1_status] => 
    [center_banner_1_display] => 0
    [center_banner_2_status] => 
    [center_banner_2_display] => 0
    [right_banner_1_status] => 
    [right_banner_1_display] => 0
    [right_banner_2_status] => 
    [right_banner_2_display] => 0
    [right_banner_3_status] => 
    [right_banner_3_display] => 0
    [right_banner_4_status] => 
    [right_banner_4_display] => 0
    [right_banner_5_status] => 
    [right_banner_5_display] => 0
    [bottom_banner_1_status] => 
    [bottom_banner_1_display] => 0 
)
```

what i am trying to achive is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [position] => top_banner_1
            [name] => Top Banner 1
            [order] => 1
            [top_banner_1_status] => 1
            [top_banner_1_display] => 0
        )
)
```

both of these arrays are comming from a database. there are 13 areas in array #1 so everything ive done so far is with foreach loops as array #2 data is fetched from a function that ideally i can't edit.

i've tried quite a few `array_*` functions but i'm not getting very far fast.

Comment: There is no built-in function for this, you have to write your own

Comment: thats the bit im struggling with as i have never had to join 2 arrays like this before

Comment: Well, you have shown us input and desired output, no code that you have been struggling with.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the following reasoning:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [position] => top_banner_1
            [name] => Top Banner 1
            [order] => 1
            [top_banner_1_status] => 1 // Added because of key is [position]_status.
            [top_banner_1_display] => 0 // Added because of key is [position]_display.
        )
)
```

I would do:

```
<?php

$array1 = // Array #1 from question.
$array2 = // Array #2 from question.

foreach ($array1 as $key => $item) {
    $position = $item['position'];
    $keySuffixes = array('_status', '_display');
    foreach ($keySuffixes as $suff) {
        if (array_key_exists($position . $suff, $array2)) {
            $array1[$key][$position . $suff] = $array2[$position . $suff];
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Not elegant, I know :(

Comment: its elegant enough but works perfectly its far far more readable than what i was comming up with. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to construct a key according to ID to fetch data from $arr2.

```
 foreach($arr1 as $key=>$val){
    $id = $val['id'];
    $tb_status_key = "top_banner_{$id}_status";
    $tb_display_key = "top_banner_{$id}_display";

    $arr1[$key][$tb_status_key] = $arr2[$tb_status_key];
    $arr1[$key][$tb_display_key] = $arr2[$tb_display_key];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure of Array #2 is not quite apprpriate for this task. If you have the possibility, you should change it to smething like this:

```
Array
(
    [top_banner_1] => Array (
      [status] => 1
      [display] => 0
    )
    [left_banner_1] => Array (
      [status] => 1
      [display] => 0
    )
)
//and so on
```

But **if** this is **not possible**, this should work:

```
foreach($array1 as &$info) {
  $status = $info['position'] . '_status';
  $display = $info['position'] . '_display';
  $info[$status] = $array2[$status];
  $info[$display] = $array2[$display];
}
```

**Otherwise**, this seems to be a more elegant way:

```
foreach($array1 as &$info) {
  $info['status'] = $array2[$info['position']]['status'];
  $info['display'] = $array2[$info['position']]['display'];
}
```